# What kind of orchid did I buy?

Tags: identification, orchids

I stumbled upon a farmers market in North California this weekend and bought this really pretty orchid, but I guess I was too excited about my purchase to ask the seller what kind of orchid it was, and there is no identification on the pot or anywhere.

[image] [image][image]

Can anyone identify what kind of orchid I bought?

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely an Oncidium, as mentioned in the comment above. I can't find an image of one with this exact coloration, but it is actually quite difficult to see detail in the pictures you provided, they do not magnify well. Image of one that's similar (with care information) here http://www.guide-to-houseplants.com/oncidium-orchid.html - scroll down and compare detail of the photo shown with your own plant, since it's not possible to see that sort of detail in your pictures.

UPDATE: Now you've posted a close up pic, it confirms your orchid as an Oncidium. This link shows one similar (first pic, third row) https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo/brown-and-yellow-orchid.html but, if you click on it, you will be able to see clearly the internal structure of the flower, which is almost exactly like yours. Unable to establish precisely which cultivar of Oncidium though.

It might be a cross breed between Oncidium and Miltonia (although still referred to as Oncidium) - see information in this thread http://everything-orchids.com/types-of-orchids/oncidium-orchid

Comment: Ah, well, if you wanted a more magnified picture, all you needed to do was ask (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctswO.jpg). Thank you for your answer. According to the American Orchid Society, the oncidium is an extraordinarily large genus, making generalizations difficult. Perhaps with the new picture you may have an inkling as to something more precise?

Answer (score 2):

This really looks like a kind of **Oncidium Sherry Baby** described in this [site](http://orchidbeginner.blogspot.fr/p/oncidium-sherry-baby.html).

Especially, they describe it as an **Oncidium Sherry Baby *Sweet Fragrance***. Did you notice any interesting chocolate smell around? However, it may need a companion flower in the room to develop the scent...

[image: Oncidium Sherry Baby *Sweet Fragrance*]

Another picture of this kind of Oncidium from the web here for example: [image: Oncidium Sherry Baby]

Answer (score 0):

I found a virtually identical orchid recently and eventually identified it as a **Red Stars Rooster**, which is, as the other answers suggest, an *Oncidium*, but as [one source claims](http://www.florafinder.com/Species/Oncidium_Red_Stars_Rooster.php), is more specifically *Cochlioda × Odontoglossum × Oncidium*.

[image: Red Stars Rooster]

Hope this helps.